# query data influxdb now() - 1s

Tags: go, influxdb

I am testing to get data from influxdb with `now() - 1s`. After done some test, all I get back is blank value, until i do `now() -3m` only get back some stable data.

```
"SELECT * FROM default.laserdistance where time >= now() - 1s" //<-- [{[] [] }]
```

Initially I thought it is impossible, because `Grafana` and `Chronograf` both don't have that option. But I read [this post](https://community.influxdata.com/t/influxdb-now-1s-is-not-working/10486). and it seems like it is actually possible. However, they did not give any sample code in final solution, so I am not sure how he solve it.

But is it actually possible? How can I get this to work in `go`?

Comment: Do you have something that's inserting values every second or faster? If not, then you're likely to get no values when you only query for the past 1s.

Comment: @Adrian I do. we have a sensor that inject at the frequency of 25 datapoint per second.